# Creation new types in go confusion

Tags: go

I have such code:

```
type ErrNegativeSqrt float64
```

Why such construct is available?

```
float64(ErrNegativeSqrt(-2))
```

Which 'mechanics' is used to store -2 in `ErrNegativeSqrt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ErrNegativeSqrt` is a `type` not a variable. Values are stored in variables.

```
type ErrNegativeSqrt float64
// x is a variable of type ErrNegativeSqrt with an initial value of -2
var x ErrNegativeSqrt = -2
```

UPDATE:

> The Go Programming Language Specification
>
> [Constants](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)
>
> There are boolean constants, rune constants, integer constants,
>   floating-point constants, complex constants, and string constants.
>   Character, integer, floating-point, and complex constants are
>   collectively called numeric constants.
>
> A constant value is represented by a rune, integer, floating-point,
>   imaginary, or string literal, an identifier denoting a constant, a
>   constant expression, a conversion with a result that is a constant, or
>   the result value of some built-in functions such as unsafe.Sizeof
>   applied to any value, cap or len applied to some expressions, real and
>   imag applied to a complex constant and complex applied to numeric
>   constants. The boolean truth values are represented by the predeclared
>   constants true and false. The predeclared identifier iota denotes an
>   integer constant.
>
> Numeric constants represent values of arbitrary precision and do not
>   overflow.
>
> Constants may be typed or untyped. Literal constants, true, false,
>   iota, and certain constant expressions containing only untyped
>   constant operands are untyped.
>
> A constant may be given a type explicitly by a constant declaration or
>   conversion, or implicitly when used in a variable declaration or an
>   assignment or as an operand in an expression.
>
> [Conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> Conversions are expressions of the form T(x) where T is a type and x
>   is an expression that can be converted to type T.

`ErrNegativeSqrt(-2)` is a conversion. The untyped constant `-2` is converted to type `ErrNegativeSqrt` because, as an operand, it can be represented in `ErrNegativeSqrt`'s  `float64` underlying type.

Comment: See my revised answer. `ErrNegativeSqrt(-2)` is a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

ErrNegativeSqrt(-2) is possible because ErrNegativeSqrt is a float64 internally, which is described by the spec as able to hold "IEEE-754 64-bit floating-point numbers".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Answer (score 1):

This is called conversions, see here: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions . It describes how a value can be created by converting another value into that type when it i compatible. And here the -2 can be represented as float64.